# How to pass the select2 dropdown value as parameter in ajax URL?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Hello everyone this is my first year studying web development, I have decided to work on a personal projet in order to get acquainted to web development world.
**EXPLANATION:** I am actually trying to design a dependent dropdown using SELECT2 dropdown and AJAX, so for a brief explanation, a customer which is normaly a company can have 1 or more printers and those printers are tracked by their code. Now i want all the printers that belong to a customer to be selected in multiple select2 dropdown once that customer is selected.
**PROBLEM:** I a using a GET type in the ajax and I find it difficult to pass the selected customer value as parameter in the url and also dynamically display the result in the second dropdown box. Can anyone help me I am so desperate, here is my code below.

PHP SERVER

```
$customerCode = $_GET['customer'];
$ivccodeArray = getPrinterCodesByCustomer($customerCode);
echo json_encode($ivccodeArray);
```

JSON ENCODING RESULTS FROM SERVER

```
[{"ivc_code":"IVC0001","model_id":"32","print_model_id":"32","print_model_name":"ECOSYS M3655idn"},
{"ivc_code":"IVC0002","model_id":"85","print_model_id":"85","print_model_name":"TASKalfa MZ4000i"},
{"ivc_code":"IVC0003","model_id":"57","print_model_id":"57","print_model_name":"TASKalfa 3212i"}]
```

HTML

```
<select name='customer' id='customer' class='form-control' required>
    <option value=''>Select a Customer</option>
    <option value="cus1">customer1</option>
    <option value="cus2">Customer2</option>
    <option value="cus3">Customer3</option>
</select>

<select name='customer' id='ivcCode' class='form-control' required multiple>
    <option value="?=ivc_code?>"><?=print_model_name?></option>
</select>
```

JS

```
<script>
$("#customer").select2({theme:"bootstrap4",placeholder:"Select an option"}),
$("#ivcCode").select2({
    theme:"bootstrap4",
    ajax: {
        url: '/mysite/call/pm/?action=printer_codes&customer',
        type: 'GET',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                $("#customer").val(),
                search: params.term
            }
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html)
            document.getElementById("ivcCode").innerHTML = html;
            $('#' + customer).select2();
        }
    },
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL of

```
'/mysite/call/pm/?action=printer_codes&customer'
```

does not specify the customer value. You will need to append it, like:

```
'/mysite/call/pm/?action=printer_codes&customer=' + $("#customer").val()
```

So, we have an `=` sign that separates the `customer` parameter from its value and we concatenate the actual value to the URL via the `+` operator.

Comment: sorry but its not working for me

Comment: @gaza please try to focus your problem description. "Not working" is very vague. Do you get an error? If so, what error do you get? Has the request been sent successfully to the server? Do you see errors in your server logs? Remember, I only know what you tell me. If someone that you want to help would only tell you that something is not working, would you be able to help?

Comment: nothing is triggered, I checked the network tab in chrome to see if there is any activity when any customer is selected but  nothing seems to work.

Comment: @gaza can you create a reproducible snippet? The docs seem to suggest that you need to pass a `data` value even for GET requests (see https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax), but I would like to test it in order to confirm. Can you create an example where this is not working so we could test our solutions there?